# size of char expression

Tags: c, sizeof

Can somebody throw a light on how `sizeof(char expression)` will be `sizeof(int)`?

```
int main()
{
char a, b;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(a+b));
return 0;
}
```

The program prints `4` as output. I was expecting it to be `sizeof(char)` i.e., `1`

Comment: in C and most languages with C-like syntax like Java, C#... types smaller than int are always promoted to int before doing operations

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Integer promotion.

When small integral types (smaller than `int`, such as `char`, `short`, etc) are in arithmetic expression, they are automatically promoted to `int`.

---

> #### C11 §6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the integer promotions. <sup>58)</sup>

And in the footnote:

> 58) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

Comment: Is it an ANSI C standard?

Comment: @Nandyy I added quote from C11. And I'm sure this is true at least since C89.

Answer (score 8):

`a+b` is an `int` expression. `a` and `b` would be `char` expressions.

When using most operators in C, operands of integral type but narrower than `int` are promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators):

> 4 If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed on them.

The usual arithmetic conversions include the integer promotion (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers):

> **If an int can represent all values of the original type** (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), **the value is converted to an int**;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions

So in this expression

```
a + b
```

the both operands are converted to type `int` and the result has this common type of operands that is `int`